# Does lower voltage mean lower power consumption?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, power, circuit-design, low-power

I am designing the architecture of an embedded system, and I have to decide between setting the power rail at 3 V or at 1.8 V.

The system will have an MCU, memory and a few sensor ICs. Depending on the voltage I would have to select some ICs or others, but I wanted to understand if there is an advantage from the power consumption side.

My intuition is that no, since the power would be the same, so at lower voltage you would have a higher current draw, but I am not sure of this. I haven't been able to find any information on the subject so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What voltage do the sensors require?

Comment: The data sheets likely tell typical current consumption at typical voltages. You need to list each part and add their power consumptions together. There is no way for us to know if your 1V8 parts consume more or less power than your 3V3 parts. Some parts require almost same amount of power to do their job regardless of voltage. You can then minimize the losses by using suitable power supplies for it.

Comment: "God is in the details." However, reducing supply voltage is a good strategy to try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can only be general guidance -- for specifics you need to scrutinize data sheets, and since part availability will be an issue, do some competing design studies.

*All else being equal*, a given CMOS circuit will tend to consume power at the clock frequency times the supply voltage squared.  But that assumes that you're running the part within its rated supply voltage and clock rate.

So for that part -- yes, maybe going low on the supply voltage is good.  But keep in mind that you also need to make regulated supplies, and regulators consume power.  Also keep in mind that sensors and analog signal processing chips tend to run a generation or two behind in their power supply requirements; that pulls your supply voltage preference upward.

Sometimes it's best to have a mixed-voltage system, with the logic powered with a lower-voltage supply than the analog stuff.

- It may be cheapest to go high, and power everything off of the same voltage.
- It may be cheapest to go low for the processor, use level converters, and power some stuff at 3.3V or higher.
- It may be cheapest to power everything off of 1.8V.

Frankly, when I'm doing circuit design I find that grinding through the design studies to make this sort of decision is what makes "work" a dirty four-letter word, but it's satisfying to be done and know you're working from a firm basis.

Answer (score 2):

Some devices, such as motors and perhaps WiFi and Bluetooth adapters, require a certain amount of power to meet design requirements, so they will draw more current at lower voltage. LEDs require a certain amount of current for a specified brightness, so if they use a series resistor, they will consume less power. But a 1.8V supply may not be enough to meet their forward voltage requirements, especially if they are higher on the spectrum (red and IR probably OK). If driven by a constant current source, the power required may be about the same for a range of supply voltage. Parts availability may also dictate design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if at all possible, **you want to set your power rail lower than your battery's lowest possible working voltage**. This simplifies a design greatly, as you don't need a boost converter.

Many ICs don't include internal voltage regulation, and will behave like [TimWescott described](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/653630/95142).

Some digital ICs (such as certain STM32 MCUs) include an internal LDO for the digital core. For those parts power consumption will go down with the voltage, as their current draw is relatively fixed for any given firmware.

Certain other parts (higher-end MCUs like i.MX RT, for example) include an internal buck converter, and their power consumption will remain relatively constant.

Overall, a lot of it depends on your standby current requirements and target BOM cost. If memory serves, Texas Instruments has some really nice 500 mA buck converters which retain above 80% efficiency at 10 uA of current load (going up to well above 90% at higher draws). Such a solution will of course be more expensive than using an LDO.